# how to get the login page in facebook using oAuth?

Tags: java

I am using socialauth to connect with socialwebsites, i am able to access few social websites but when i try to access facebook, i get the following exception.

I use java

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Invalid redirect_uri: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 191
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its says the redirectURI that you are giving in the request is not same which you have given during your app configuration in facebook. both should be same.

Comment: See this link http://support.newscloud.com/kb/installing-newscloud/how-to-register-your-application-with-facebook , may remind you your redirect url in application registration on facebook.